# sql case statement IN with group by

Tags: sql, case

I have a 2 column table with the columns : "user_name" and "characteristic".   Each user_name may appear multiple times with a different characteristic.

The values in characteristic are:

- Online
- Instore
- Account
- Email

I want to write a sql statement that goes like this - but obviously this isn't working:

```
SELECT user_name, 
       case 
          when characteristic in ("online","instore") then 1 
          else 0 
       END as purchase_yn, 
       case 
          when characteristic in ("online","instore") and 
               characteristic in ("email",'account')   then 1 
          else 0 
       END as   purchaser_with_account 
 FROM my_table 
 GROUP BY user_name;
```

Essentially the first is a flag where I check for the presence of either value for that user_name.
The Second field  is that they  meet this criteria AND that they meet the criteria for having either 'email' or 'account'

Comment: this is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I assume you're meaning the use of double quotes? (And mixing them with single quotes). I didn't make too much of it since he also said that code doesn't work ... Only it looks like there must be two ways in which it fails. Still would be good to know the DBMS.

Comment: @runningbirds, do any of the answers below meet your needs? If so, you should mark it as "accepted". If not, please come back and let us know how about the remaining problems (and answer the question of what DBMS you're using: e.g SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, MS-Access, something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example the structure of your data would help better understand what you are trying to accomplish.  But I think I get what you are trying to do.

You have to use an aggregate function in order to use a group by.
Something like SUM or AVG.

But you need first to build a pivot of your data and then you could use that pivot to check for your criterias:

This would create a table pivot that shows for each record what criterias are met:

```
SELECT 
   user_name, 
   case when characteristic = "online"  then 1 else 0 end as online_yn,
   case when characteristic = "instore" then 1 else 0 end as instore_yn,
   case when characteristic = "account" then 1 else 0 end as account_yn,
   case when characteristic = "email"   then 1 else 0 end as email_yn,
FROM my_table
```

Now what you might wanted to do is to create an averaged version of these entries grouped by `user_name` and use those averages to create the fields you wanted.  For that you need to use the same statement created earlier as an inline table :

```
Select
   user_name,
   case when avg(online_yn + instore_yn) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end as purchase_yn,
   case when avg(online_yn + instore_yn) >= 1 and avg(email_yn + account_yn) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end as purchaser_with_account
From
    (SELECT 
       user_name, 
       case when characteristic = "online"  then 1 else 0 end as online_yn,
       case when characteristic = "instore" then 1 else 0 end as instore_yn,
       case when characteristic = "account" then 1 else 0 end as account_yn,
       case when characteristic = "email"   then 1 else 0 end as email_yn,
     FROM my_table) avg_table

group by
   user_name;
```

This should help.

It may not be efficient in terms of performance but you'll get what you want.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't use AVG for this. MAX or SUM seems much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to enclose the `CASE` expressions in `COUNT` aggregates:

```
SELECT user_name, 
       COUNT(case when characteristic in ("online","instore") then 1 END) as purchase_yn, 
       COUNT(case when characteristic in ("email",'account') then 1 END) as user_with_account
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY user_name
```

If `purchase_yn > 0` then you first flag is set. If `purchase_yn > 0` *and* `user_with_account > 0` then you second flag is set as well.

**Note:** You have to remove `ELSE 0` from the `CASE` expressions because `COUNT` takes into account *all not null* values.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned a specific RDBMS, but if `SUM(DISTINCT ...)` is available the following is quite nice:

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(DISTINCT
        CASE
            WHEN characteristic in ('online','instore') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS purchase_yn,
    CASE WHEN (
        SUM(DISTINCT
            CASE
                WHEN characteristic in ('online','instore') THEN 1
                WHEN characteristic in ('email','account') THEN 2
            ELSE 0 END
       )
    ) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchaser_with_account
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    username
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, if user have 'online' or 'instore', then for this user you want 1 as `purchase_yn` column, and if user also have  'email' or 'account', then 1 as `purchaser_with_account` column.

If this is correct, then one way is:

```
with your_table(user_name, characteristic) as(
    select 1, 'online' union all
    select 1, 'instore' union all
    select 1, 'account' union all
    select 1, 'email' union all
    select 2, 'account' union all
    select 2, 'email' union all
    select 3, 'online'  
)

-- below is actual query:

select your_table.user_name, coalesce(max(t1.purchase_yn), 0) as purchase_yn, coalesce(max(t2.purchaser_with_account), 0) as purchaser_with_account 
from your_table
left join (SELECT user_name, 1 as purchase_yn from your_table where characteristic in('online','instore') ) t1
on your_table.user_name = t1.user_name
left join (SELECT user_name, 1 as purchaser_with_account  from your_table where characteristic in('email', 'account') ) t2 
on t1.user_name = t2.user_name
group by your_table.user_name
```